# HTML5, height calculation with overflow hidden

Tags: html, overflow

Why HTML5, in this example, made ​​a difference in the calculation of the height of the child element if overflow is set to hidden on the parent ? Without HTML5 doctype and/or overflow, the text is displayed without it is hidden.

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not possible have parent as overflow hidden as as well as relative positioning. Instead of that you can put addition child and make it to flow overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible have parent as overflow hidden as as well as relative positioning. Instead of that you can put addition child and make it to flow overflow.

A better example for that usage is see below.

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.another-child {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="another-child">
        Another child containing a long text with overflow property as hidden
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```